# ReactJS: Updating each element of a state array, with a different value

Tags: reactjs, state

I would like a little bit of help with the following situation in React JS:
I have a state in one of my components which is an array of 3 json objects, like this:

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([ {name:'a'}, {name:'b'}, {name:'c'}])
```

And i also have an array of 3 random names:

```
const randomArray = ['d', 'e', 'f']
```

I wanna make a method that will take as an argument the `randomArray` and will update the new state like this:

```
data = [ {name:'d'}, {name:'e'}, {name:'f'}]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the map function. It returns a new array from the callback function. You can return the name property like so;

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { name: "a" },
    { name: "b" },
    { name: "c" }
  ]);
  const randomArray = ["d", "e", "f"];

  const setNewValues = () => {
    setData(randomArray.map(name=> ({ name})));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data);
  }, [data]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={setNewValues}>Set Data </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
If my initial state instead of one attribute per json  [{ name: 'a' }, etc.] , had two attributes for each json (e.g [{name:'a', number:4}, {name:'b', number:3}, {name:'c', number:2}] ), what would be the solution then?  The final state I would like to have in this example is this: data = [ {name:'d' , number:4 } , {name:'e', number:3} , {name:'f', number:2} ]

Comment: you would then fully declare the callback function from map like so;

`setData(randomArray.map((item,index)=> { 
    return {
        name:item.name,
        number:item.number
    }
}));`

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can do it.

```
const ArrChange = () => {
 const randomArray = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
 const [data, setData] = useState([ {name:'a'}, {name:'b'}, {name:'c'}]) 
 const setData = () => {
   for(let i = 0; i < randomArray.lenght; i++)
      d[i].name = randomArray[i];
 }

 <Button onClick={setData}>
          Update
      </Button>
 }
```

Comment: You are re-defining the function returned by the hook. Don't do that.

Comment: @Janez please correct my code appreciated (y)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! :)

```
const convertToJSON = array => {
  setData(array.map(name => ({ name })));
};
```

Comment: *Code without an explanation is rarely useful, however. At least provide a sentence or two to explain what’s going on.* [Answering Technical Questions Helpfully](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/)